# Where would I find the kernel .config file in Lubuntu?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu

I'm running through the "first kernel patch" tutorial on kernel newbies http://kernelnewbies.org/FirstKernelPatch

While running through the tutorial, i've had absolutely no issues what so ever until now, I am at a point where I am setting up my kernel configuration. I've followed the tutorial exactly as shown but the following command:

```
cp /boot/config-'uname -r'* .config
```

leaves me with the following error message in the terminal:

```
cp: cannot stat '/boot/config-uname -r*': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way I  can generate this file without going through the effort of looking for it in the finder? I'd rather not go through the thousands of files there are in a kernel, it could take me forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your tutorial has a quotation error. instead of <kbd>'</kbd> you should be using <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick)

```
cp /boot/config-`uname -r`* .config
```

What it does is execute the command `uname -r` and place the stdout of the command in place of the command. I'd suggest using `$(command)` instead of `` `command` `` since it's more obvious what is going on.

```
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r)* .config
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It's worked. I was getting so frustrated this morning with it.

Answer (score 2):

First things first .. You're using simple quotes which is wrong, the command is meant to use backticks (`) -- they will include the output of the command inside them:

```
> uname -r
3.16.1-ck1
> echo /boot/config-`uname -r`
/boot/config-3.16.1-ck1
```

So this could already solve your problem.

If this file isn't present on your system, you have some alternatives:

1. If you have the source the running kernel is built from, the kernel config is the file `.config` there.
2. Although most packaging/installation systems copy the kernel config to `` /boot/config-`uname -r` ``, some just copy it to `/boot/config` (without version suffix)
3. The kernel can be built to serve it's config in `/proc/config.gz` (gzip compressed)

If really neither of these succeed, you're out of luck and your only option is get hold of the source package your kernel is built from.